# How to suppress DDL log

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I am writing an app that uses MySQL in a "non-standard" way, so to say. It relies heavily on dynamically created/dropped tables.

So far it's functioning properly. The specs don't make me happy, though. Whenever I run them, I get tons of activerecord's ddl log messages. See for yourself:

```
SqlDailyEvents
-- create_table("11_daily_events_20120428")
   -> 0.0032s
  should create and drop a table
-- create_table("11_daily_events_20120428")
   -> 0.0030s
  should not create the same table twice
  should not drop the same table twice
```

That's `--format d`. With `--format p` it looks even worse!

How do I turn it off? This log seems not to be affected by `ActiveRecord::Base.logger` (which I tried setting to `nil`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*deleted the code with Kernel method that manipulates `$stdout`*)

It was ActiveRecord, after all. Seems that if you define migrations the "new" way (with `change` method instead of `up`/`down` pair), it doesn't spam you as much. Anyway, it has a similar method, but it manipulates Migration's verbosity, not `$stdout`.

Now my code looks like this:

```
  def up
    # built-in method. sets verbose flag to false
    suppress_messages do
      create_table table_name do |t|
        t.column :username, :string
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: There has to be a better way. Do you know who is producing those messages? Is it ActiveRecord or the MySQL driver?

Comment: I didn't find out so far. Hence this quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: @muistooshort: got it, does it look better now? :)

Comment: Better. But do you really need to use migrations for this at all? I get the impression that that `connection.execute('create table ...')` would be more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: No, I don't really need migrations. But this way logic for forming table name stays close to the code that creates/drops tables. This seems to be a good thing. Also, having migrations should lessen the pain, should I decide to move to postgres.